# How to convert a binary to a base10 (decimal) integer in elixir

Tags: encoding, int, erlang, elixir, radix

I would like to be able to convert an elixir string(binary) to a base10 integer.

I have been able to do this with the following...

```
<<104, 101, 108, 108, 111>> # equal to string "hello"
|> Base.encode16()
|> Integer.parse(16)

{448378203247, ""}
```

The above does what I am after but, feels a little like a hack. I would like to...

- better understand what exactly is happening here
- know if/how I would be able to do this in one step

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Elixir strings are just binaries, you could probably use the erlang `:binary.decode_unsigned` function to convert binary digits to integers

From the documentation 
http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#decode_unsigned-1

```
iex> :binary.decode_unsigned("hello")
448378203247

iex> :binary.encode_unsigned(448378203247)
"hello"
```

Essentially, the ascii values of `hello` is

```
<<104, 101, 108, 108, 111>>
```

when converted from decimal to hex can be written as

```
<<68, 65, 6C, 6C, 6F>>
```

or in binary as

```
<01101000, 01100101, 01101100, 01101100, 01101111>
```

which is a series of bytes stored as

`68656C6C6F` in hex or

`01101000_01100101_01101100_01101100_01101111` in binary

whose decimal(base-10) value would be `448378203247`

```
iex> Integer.to_string(448378203247, 16)
"68656C6C6F"

iex> Integer.to_string(448378203247, 2)
"110100001100101011011000110110001101111"
# each byte separated by _ is
# "1101000_01100101_01101100_01101100_01101111"
# missing a leading zero at the left, which doesn't change the value
```

edit: added binary example,

also, two hex digits can be used to perfectly denote a byte(4 bits needed to encode 16 values, 0 to 15)
which is why when we denote in hex, we can just concatenate the hex values and not when they are in decimal(base-10) notation

From [The wiki for hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

> Hexadecimal numerals are widely used by computer system designers and programmers, as they provide a more human-friendly representation of binary-coded values. Each hexadecimal digit represents four binary digits, also known as a nibble, which is half a byte. For example, a single byte can have values ranging from 0000 0000 to 1111 1111 in binary form, which can be more conveniently represented as 00 to FF in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 4):

**Convert binary (base 2) number to a decimal (base 10) number in Elixir:**

`Integer.parse("1111111", 2) |> elem(0)` gives 127

`:erlang.binary_to_integer(<<"1111111">>, 2)` gives 127

While this doesn't answer the OP's example above, it answers his headline.

[Also](http://daisymolving.github.io/2016/07/12/binary-octal-hexadecimal.html): Elixir gives us shortcuts in its interactive console (IEx) to convert binary, octal and hexadecimal numbers to decimal numbers. Prefix your number with `0b` if it's binary, `0o` if it's octal or `0x` if it's hexidecimal, and it outputs the decimal version.

So `0b1111111` gives 127 in IEx.

**Convert decimal to a binary number in Elixir:**

`Integer.to_string(127, 2)` gives "1111111"